# Execution time of NP and NP-Complete algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, np

For P algorithms, we say that the execution time can be logarithmic O(log n), lineal O(n), quadratic O(n^2), etc.

For NP and NP-Complete algorithms is there a way to represent the execution time? Or is there a 'standard' way of doing it?

Comment: The answer is in the definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Asymptotic (/Big-Oh/Landau) notation is not special to polynomial time algorithms, or indeed any class of algorithm. It *is* the standard way of communicating (asymptotic) running times, amongst other resources.

So we say that binary search runs in time $O(\log n)$ because that is what its asymptotic running time is, and hence the **Searching** *problem* in $\mathrm{P}$, but not it is in $\mathrm{P}$ and hence we can get some $O(\cdot)$ expression for it. The [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem has an $O(2^{n})$ algorithm for example (in fact $\Theta(2^{n})$), this happens to put it in the class [$\mathrm{EXP}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) , but the asymptotic expression is still an evaluation of the running time, regardless of which class it is in.

Note the distinction here between problems an algorithms as well. A *problem* is in a complexity class, and *algorithm* has a running time. By extension we say that the problem can be solved in time "blah" *because it has an algorithm runnning in that time*. So we can't have an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete algorithm, only an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem. We can abuse the language a small amount an say we have and $\mathrm{NP}$ algorithm, but what we mean is that we have  a nondeterministic polynomial time algorithm, i.e. an algorithm that demonstrates that whatever problem it's for is in $\mathrm{NP}$, just as binary search is a polynomial time algorithm that demonstrates that **Searching** (the formally defined problem) is in $\mathrm{P}$. Then David Richerby's answer applies - they're just polynomial but on a nondeterministic machine, i.e. $O(n^{c})$ for some fixed $c$.

On the flip side, we can have an algorithm for an $\mathrm{NP}$ problem that is not the one that shows that the problem is in $\mathrm{NP}$. For example, there's an algorithm for the **Travelling Salesman Problem** that just tries all the possibilities. This algorithm has running time $O(n!)$. It's not the best algorithm, but it is an algorithm for an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem, and that's its running time expressed asymptotically.

Finally, $\mathrm{P}$ is a subclass of $\mathrm{NP}$, so all those "P algorithms" are also "NP algorithms" - they just don't use the nondeterminism.

Answer (score 3):

An **NP** algorithm is, by definition, one that runs in polynomial time on a nondeterministic Turing machine.